# Adding a download button to entire couse as a pdf in learndash plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I'm developing an on-line course using the Learndash Plugin in wordpress. I've add a plugin post2pdf for downloading a single lesson as a pdf, but I also want the entire course to be downloadable as a pdf.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this, either using the same plugin, or with any other plugin?